# Add labels on calendar view

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

I am working on a project in which I have integrated full screen calendar view for iPad.

The `ios_calendar` view which is available on cocoa controls [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ios-calendar).

Now, what I want is to add labels on various dates.

Also single label to be shown, which would stretch from starting date to ending date.

Any solution to this?

I can make changes by this method if I want to add views in `Selected Date Cell`.
But couldn't find how to put label on some other date of the year .

```
- (void) calendarView: (CXCalendarView *) calendarView
        didSelectDate: (NSDate *) date {

    NSLog(@"Selected date: %@",date);

    UILabel *labeltext=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 50, 50)];
    labeltext.text=@"hello";
    labeltext.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.calendarView addSubview:labeltext];

}
```

Comment: Please post any code where you have tried to do this your self. From here we can better help you where you are going the wrong way.

Comment: Its a view and you can add labels as subviews on top of it. How one should do it is the logic part which you haven't explained in the question

Comment: @PraveenS Yes, its a view and i can add subviews on the main view.But that is not what i want. Secondly you are right that its the logic part to take out some particular date and add label into that specific cell. How to do that for this ios_calendar? Any idea?

Comment: @rckoenes I have put some code but that is just a single method to work with the selected date. Also there are many files of other methods as well in the project to create the grid and cells.Please have a look at the link mentioned above.